# nuxt-purgecss with mdb-vue not working in production

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am attempting to implement nuxt-purgecss into my nuxt project, I am also using mdb-vue(Material Design Bootstrap).

It seems to be working fine in dev,.. 
but after I build with 'nuxt generate' or 'npm run generate'

I have tried with both 'with-nuxt-manual' and 'with-nuxt-module' from
https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/tree/master/examples

both give the same results, css is purged in dev, but not after nuxt generate

here is my manual mode config..

nuxt-config.js

```js
import path from 'path'
import PurgecssPlugin from 'purgecss-webpack-plugin'
import glob from 'glob-all'

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  css: ['bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'mdbvue/build/css/mdb.css'],

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    'nuxt-fontawesome',
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
  ],
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient, loaders: { vue } }) {
      if (isClient) {
        vue.transformAssetUrls.img = ['data-src', 'src']
        vue.transformAssetUrls.source = ['data-srcset', 'srcset']
      }
      if (!isDev && isClient) {
        // Remove unused CSS using purgecss. See https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss
        // for more information about purgecss.
        config.plugins.push(
          new PurgecssPlugin({
            paths: glob.sync([
              path.join(__dirname, './pages/**/*.vue'),
              path.join(__dirname, './layouts/**/*.vue'),
              path.join(__dirname, './components/**/*.vue')
            ]),
            whitelist: ['html', 'body']
          })
        )
      }
    },
    transpile: ['mdbvue']
  }
}
```

I can not seem to find any documentation for configuring webpack for bootstrap/mdb with purgecss.

Answer (score 0):

I have I solved the problem, I am pretty sure pwa and cached files were giving me confusing results.

With my current working nuxt.config.js(see below)

- I test in dev mode "npm run dev" and css is not purged(what I want).
- then I run "npm run generate" and test locally, css is purged(what I want).
- then I push to github dev branch, netlify builds and deploys a staging subdomain, I test there,.. css is purged(what I want).
- finally I merge the dev branch with master, and push to github, netlify builds and deploys to production, I test there css is purged(what I want).

```js
  build: {
    extractCSS: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient, loaders: { vue } }) {
      if (isClient) {
        vue.transformAssetUrls.img = ['data-src', 'src']
        vue.transformAssetUrls.source = ['data-srcset', 'srcset']
      }
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.plugins.push(
          new PurgecssPlugin({
            paths: glob.sync([
              path.join(__dirname, './pages/**/*.vue'),
              path.join(__dirname, './layouts/**/*.vue'),
              path.join(__dirname, './components/**/*.vue')
            ]),
            whitelist: ['html', 'body']
          })
        )
      }
    },
    transpile: ['mdbvue']
  }
```